# Syntax error or access violation mysql Raw query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
  $sqlQuery ="SELECT
           DISTINCT
          media_albume.albume_id,
         media_albume.albume_tittle,
            media_albume.created_user,
         CONCAT('$base_url',media.url) AS image_url
           FROM
         media_albume
        INNER JOIN media ON media.albume_id = media_albume.albume_id
         WHERE
        created_user =$userId 
        GROUP BY
       media.albume_id";

      $results = DB::select($sqlQuery);
       /**this is my code ** /
```

> when i run  this code with out  "Group By " it work  after adding Group By it triggerd below error
>    "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 "

Comment: You need to GROUP BY all the columns you are SELECTing; except for any aggregate columns - https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php

Comment: And try Eloquent models and relationships. Your code and life will be lot simpler. That's the essence of Laravel.

Comment: Laravel by default enables strict mode for MySQL which does prevent selecting columns that aren't aggregated.  You need to either adjust your query or disable strict mode in config/database.php.

Comment: Syntax error its`media_albume` not `media`

Comment: @Devon : Thank you very much for you support  & quick response .. it worked bro .

Comment: Laravel's Eloquent ORM gives you a lot of ways to avoid injecting things like `$userId` directly in your query, something that's a possible [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Try to avoid doing that unless it's absolutely necessary, and if it is, be 100% certain that value is properly escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel by default enables strict mode for MySQL which does prevent selecting columns that aren't aggregated when using group by.

You need to either adjust your query or disable strict mode in config/database.php.

I would recommend re-working your code to work with strict mode though (only select columns that are grouped/aggregated).